# gunicorn running with flask in python hangs when started?

Tags: python, flask, keras, gunicorn

I am running a Python script containing `keras` models which should be run with a flask app and `gunicorn`. The flask server on it's own runs fine, but when I try to integrate `gunicorn` with it, the worker hangs after boot. These are the last 2 statements that I see :

```
[2018-01-26 12:17:35 +0000] [32225] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32225
2018-01-26 12:17:36.651087: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
```

I can no longer access flask in the browser after integrating `gunicorn`. This is the main problem. I tried lowering the timeout for workers but it did not make a difference.

Comment: the one output you show is a warning that won't affect the `gunicorn`, so report other errors pls

Comment: @lorenzori that's the problem. there are no errors. it just hangs after showing these warnings. however i cannot execute my GET requests which i was able to do previously in flask without guicorn

Comment: nope that is not the problem, is standard you get this warning when you run on CPU (I get it as well). And is just a warning, not an error. Try to debug something else.

Answer (score 0):

i got it fixed. the issue was related to installing libraries within my script some of which were missing for which i used sudo -H instead of sudo which soved the issue.